# jQuery Create element inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

I've seen many guides online for create a new element in jQuery such as the following code

```
var input = $('<input>', {
    id: 'FormUsername',
    name: 'username',
    type: 'text',
    value: 'Enter your username...',
    focusin: function() {
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).appendTo(someElement);
```

This creates one input element and appends it. I want to create a div element and add this input element to it and then append it. How would i go about doing that?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Append and add is same thing in above context. Your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap your element into another one before appending it:

```
var input = $('<input>', {
    id: 'FormUsername',
    name: 'username',
    type: 'text',
    value: 'Enter your username...',
    focusin: function() {
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).wrap('<div/>').parent().appendTo(someElement);
```

*Note: you'd have to call .parent() because .wrap() does **not** return the wrapping element*

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/xzrTx/)**

---

You could also do it in several steps if you need to add attributes to the wrapping div, syntax is similar:

```
var input = $('<input>', { ... });

// create a div element with an ID=wrapper
$('<div/>', { id: 'wrapper' })
    // append the input to it
    .append(input)
    // append the div to "someElement"
    .appendTo(someElement);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/g7ndd/)**

Answer (score 1):

Same syntax, really:

```
var input = $('<input>', {
    id: 'FormUsername',
    name: 'username',
    type: 'text',
    value: 'Enter your username...',
    focusin: function() {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});

var div = $('<div>', {
    id: 'SomeWrapperDiv'
}).append(input);

div.appendTo(someElement);
```

Comment: Verbose... why not use `wrap`?

Comment: @gdoron: See comment on ShankarSangoli's answer by the OP below.

Comment: @gdoron: I'm confused; why is it a problem that there are requirements to have an `id` attribute?

Comment: It's o.k. but he just did it with the input, do just do the same with  the div, why are you asking??? (I blame him, not you...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  var input = $('<input>', {
    id: 'FormUsername',
    name: 'username',
    type: 'text',
    value: 'Enter your username...',
    focusin: function() {
        $(this).val('');
    }
  })
  $('<div>', {
    id: 'divId',
    class: 'className'
  })
  .append(input)
  .appendTo(someElement);
```

Comment: but i want to add an id and classes to the div also using the same way i did with the input.

Comment: `wrap` returns the original set of elements, not the wrappers.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - I think `wrap` will return the element wrapped with element you pass.

Comment: But if you call append it will only append the original elements to the dom.  http://jsfiddle.net/xzrTx/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use the wrap function:

```
var input = $('<input>', {
id: 'FormUsername',
name: 'username',
type: 'text',
value: 'Enter your username...',
focusin: function() {
    $(this).val('');
}
}).wrap('<div></div>').parent().appendTo(someElement);
```

wrap [docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: `wrap` returns the original set of elements, not the wrappers.

Comment: @JamesMontagne. Right. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/Eek7N/1/

```
var div = $("<div>");

var input = $('<input>', {
id: 'FormUsername',
name: 'username',
type: 'text',
value: 'Enter your username...',
focusin: function() {
    $(this).val('');
}
});

div.html("I'm the div");

div.append(input);

$("body").append(div);​
```

Answer (score 0):

And another way:

```
$('#someElement').append($('<span></span>').append(input));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xcZjt/